# django group permissions for online collaboration

Tags: django, authentication, permissions

I am working on a database project for different users in Django, but I don't understand nearly enough about the idea of groups and permissions to know where to start for allowing users to collaborate on projects.

Essentially, I want each project (and its entries) to be owned by the person who created it (this part I have covered), but I also want users to be able to add usernames for other users onto each project (and its entries) so that other users can view the project, the entries, update them and create new entries for that project.

Also I want it to display only projects & entries that the user has either created or is a collaborator on.

I've never worked with permissions before and while I'm reading through "Using the Django authentication system" I'm not having much luck getting my head around it. Are there any good writeups on how to incorporate this or maybe something from another perspective or a tutorial?

I had originally made a text field column where a user could add usernames of fellow collaborators, then the views would check it and if one of the usernames matched the logged in user, it would allow them to view that project, but it sounds like this is not the secure way to go.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not have a ManyToMany field to Users? Then check if one of those Users is logged in.

Comment: Are you saying that essentially the user access list would be a many to many field where, say the form itself would be a charfield, they could type in the username, then the views would extract the username, pull the appropriate user then save it in the many to many field with other users? Then when a user is logged in, the database checks their username against the many to many field to see if they've got access and displays it then?

Comment: No, that would defeat the whole point of it. I'd use a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) with `queryset=User.objects.all()`. This allows you to have a list of user names, which you can select from, without needing to type in the username.

Comment: I guess I'm confused because there's a two step process that I'm not getting. One is that there needs to be a way that a user who creates a project needs a way to input usernames to collaborate with into the project, so they can view the project, entries, and create new ones. But I also need a way to display to a user projects & entries they can view. So if I use a ModelMultipleChoiceField, would that be a form they can type usernames into? Or does it display all usernames and they click which ones they want as collaborators?

Comment: The second. It would be a box which displays all the usernames (well, all the usernames you want it to. If you filter the queryset, you can define a subset of all usernames if you want). Displaying the projects a user has access to becomes simple, because you can filter the object (that has the ManyToMany field to user) like so: `objects = YourObject.objects.filter(allowed_user == request.user)`. I'm not sure that syntax is 100% correct. Look up Django's documentation of filtering ManyToMany fields.